# localhost:8888 to localhost MAMP PRO mac

Tags: apache, mamp, mamp-pro

Ever since moving to MAMP PRO the localhost URL looks like http://localhost:8888, I'd like to change it to the default http://localhost without the port 8888

I tried several solutions including updating to port 80, but when I do that it just shows page cannot be displayed. Below is the window where I replace 8888 to 80

[image]

Also updated MAMP and tried modifying the hosts file, but it didn't help.

I notice that MAMP is adding these entries to the hosts file, can I modify them to make it redirect from localhost:8888 to simply localhost?

[image]

Comment: Is there anything esle running on port 80? Did you restart Apache after making the changes?

Comment: Hi Jay, I checked if anything's running on port 80 with "sudo lsof -i :80 # checks port 80" but it came up empty, and also restarted apache using "sudo apachectl stop"